# window.location in Firefox and Chrome giving me two different returned strings for a Google Macro

Tags: url, browser, google-apps-script

My application is using Google Apps Script HTML Service.  The URL for Apps Script looks like this:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby2Zr2apAai2sIW6eiWTc8yNakGg5M9oLQkmhcz-IRqs22qoJhm/exec
```

In Firefox, this line of code:

```
window.daURL = window.location;
```

returns this:

```
 https://script.google.com/macros/blank
```

Firefox puts in the word `blank`.  Chrome gives me the entire URL.
What I've been doing, is getting the entire URL, then using Javascript string methods to parse the URL for whatever info I need to check for a Facebook login.  The Facebook login appends info to the end of the URL beginning with a hash tag.  If the hash tag is there, the code checks for and validates a Facebook login.

I need either the entire URL, or to be able to get an appended string after the `/exec`.

Chrome gives me the entire URL with `window.location`, but Firefox will not.

If I try:

```
window.daURL = window.location.pathname;
```

Firefox returns:

```
/macros/blank
```

If I try:

```
window.daURL = window.location.search;
```

I get nothing returned, even when a string is appended to the URL.

I can get a string appended to the URL with the Apps Scripts `doGet(e)` function:

```
e.parameter.theNameOfTheStringArg
```

E.g.  www.URL.com?myArg=Something

Use: `var getString = e.parameter.myArg`

But I can't get a hashed appended value to the URL with `doGet(e)`.  I need to check for a hash in the URL.

Comment: doGet(e) cannot access the hash value because browsers typically do not pass it to the server.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can use `window.location.href` to check for the existence of the hash tag appended to the url.  So I use `window.onload` to check for a hashtag in the url, and `doGet(e)` to check for string attachments to the URL.  I need to run both.

```
<script>
//Script tag in first HTML file that always loads

window.onload=function(){
  console.log("This onload did run");

  //get the URL out of the browsers address bar
  //the URL can have multiple different strings attached depending upon the situation.
  //Any situation other than something with a hashtag is initiated in the back end.

  window.daURLhash = window.location.hash;
  console.log('daURLhash: ' + daURLhash);

  window.urlHash = daURLhash.toString();
  console.log('urlHash: ' + urlHash);

  console.log("url: " + urlHash);
  //If a certain situation, there will be a hashtag in the url string
  if (urlHash != undefined && urlHash != null) {
    if (urlHash.length > 0) {
      window.hashExist = true;
      console.log('hashExist: ' + hashExist); 
    };
  };

  if (window.hashExist === true) {
     code here

</script>
```

Comment: Also:  I can get the location.hash value in client-side javascript when you're using sandbox = NATIVE.  I have not been able to get it when sandbox = IFRAME.