# CakePHP: How to pass url with anchor through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I want to pass a certain url with anchor to cakephp as parameter. 
my ajax is as follows:

```
var next_url = 'www.domain.com/search#!query=blah%20secondBlah&times=5';
$.ajax({
    url : '/users/login/?next='+next_url,
    success: function(res) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

In my controller, I run

```
debug($this->request->query['next']);
```

and it gets me only `www.domain.com/search` without the anchor part.

What to do?

CakePHP 2.3

Comment: what do you have in your controller?

Comment: Why do you want to use such an anchor?

Comment: @IsaacRajaei what do you mean?

Comment: try @Brain Glaz answer first and read my comment below it. You will be able to get the next. try that if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url). What you're trying to do is fundamentally not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would send `next_url` in the data option of `$.ajax` so it is properly URL encoded. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/users/login/',
    data: {next: next_url},
    success: function(res) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: debug($this->request->query['next']); should be debug($this->request->data['next']);

Comment: @IsaacRajaei I'm not sure.. does using `data` automatically turn it into a POST request? If it remains GET, I believe jQuery will just append it as a query string.

Comment: `$this->request->data['next']` returns `Undefined index: next`.

Comment: @mgPePe I believe Isaac was incorrect, stick with your original `debug($this->request->query['next']);`

Comment: Passing as data: {next: next_url} works indeed, but I still have the same problem on the non-ajax version, which I also need working. `http://www.domain.dev/login?next=http://www.domain.dev/search#!search_term=blah%20&times=5`

Comment: you can use JS to encode the URL, and then it should work. Try `next_url = encodeURIComponent('www.domain.com/search#!query=blah%20secondBlah&times=5');`

Comment: That works half-way because my `&amps` get screwed when I debug `$this->request->query['next']`: `www.domain.com/search#!query=blah%20secondBlah&amp;times=5`. It seems that CakePHP somehow autodecodes it, but through a different mechanism than Javascript's `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: after you retrieve it in cake, try using `html_entity_decode()` on it to get the `&` back.

Comment: Unfortunately this also converts the %20 and I am left with ` ` in the url :(