# Laravel routing Ajax hashtagged URL

Tags: ajax, laravel-4, hashtag, laravel-routing

I just bought a single page template ( [smartadmin](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0573SK0) ) which loads contents using ajax and change url using a pattern "/#ajax/file.html".

I was surprised that I can navigate through it without setting routes, and even if I set a route it doesn't work. Example :

> Route::get('/#ajax/inbox.php', function() {   return
>   View::make('test'); });

How should I do the routing?

Comment: the problem is, everything after the `#` will not be processed by the backend, only handled in the front-end itself.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way to manage routes in a single page application that loads pages through ajax?
That's weird, because I can call php scripts after the `#`.

Comment: that's what ajax is doing. the portion after `#` just executes a request, which does not contain any hashtags at all. in your smartadmin example, it simply gets an html page and replaces it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in my comment, you can't grab the portion of the url after the `#`.

more infos: [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

In the ng.app.js file there is a line that will look like this

`smartApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$provide', function($routeProvider, $provide) {`

in that code you'll see something like `return 'views/'+ $routeParams.page +'.html';` thats where the angular js version of smart admin makes the request. maybe this will help you.

sorry if you are not using the angular version of smart admin. I just bought it my self and I am struggling to laravel it up..