# How to get HashTag in Cakephp Form Submit?

Tags: cakephp, hashtag

I am working in cakephp 2.x

my current url is `http://sitename.com/users/edit_profile#step-2` when i submit page i am not getting `#setp-2`

Code:

```
//Setp-2
<?php echo $this->form->create('User',array('action'=>'edit_profile')); ?>
    <label>Smoke</label>
    <?php $smoke_option = array('Heavy'=>'Heavy','Moderate'=>'Moderate','Light'=>'Light','Occasional'=>'Occasional','Non Smoker'=>'Non Smoker','Herb'=>'Herb');
    echo $this->form->input('smoke', array('options' => $smoke_option,'default'=>$getProfile['User_detail']['smoke'],'label'=>false,'div'=>false,'empty'=>'No Answer'));?>
  </div>
<?php echo $this->form->end();?>
```

UsersController.php

```
public function edit_profile(){
    $this->layout='default';        
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $data['User']['id']=$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        $updateProfile=$this->User->add_details($data);
        if($updateProfile){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Profile Updated Successfully'), 'success_message');
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }
    }
}
```

How to getting hashtag in cakephp form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
array('action'=>'edit_profile', '#' => 'step-2')
```

It appends #step-2 as you need in the url, similarly you can use your for ? also

Answer (score 0):

The hash is never sent to the server.

ref - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url`

though you can set a hidden field and set the value  = .

you can access the hash by `document.location.hash`