# Submit button works only as link to anchor

Tags: php, html, cross-browser

I have the following code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="search_form" name="search_form" action="thisfile.php#anchorname" method="get">

<!-- Lots of search fields here -->

<input name="search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
// Search in database
?>
<div id="anchorname">
<!-- Table with results here -->
</div>
<?php
}
```

This works fine in IE (crazy, I know) but in Chrome and Firefox, after the form is submitted and the results table is displayed, the button doesn't resubmit the form but only makes the page scroll down to anchorname. In Chrome I can reload the page by clicking on the address bar and hitting enter, but when I do that in Firefox, nothing happens at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of a div anchor, try `<a name="anchorname"></a>` and wrap the div around it and don't name it, or name it something else.

Comment: Encode hash in form action with `%23`

Comment: Tried both, neither suggestion works.

Comment: However, PHP doesn't recognize hashtags when it comes to anchoring. You'll need to use a client-side method. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/940905/

Comment: Use POST method, especially because you use `multipart/form-data` encoding.

Comment: ^^^^^ exactly; I missed that. If you're going to want to upload/attach files, you must use POST. If you're not going to offer either of those, just remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"`; you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks! I've removed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and I'm now using a client-side method. I'm still puzzled though: why is it possible to submit but not resubmit?

Comment: Got caught by this today as well. Very strange behavior. Didn't find a bug report on this anywhere (except for one for Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to anyone, here's what I did, using JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // ...
    <?php if (isset($_GET['search'])) { ?>
        var target = $("#anchorname");
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
    <?php } ?>
});
```