# Get Anchor value from url using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get anchor value from URL using ruby.

> http://{My-Domain}/signin#recording

Want to get **#recording** value.

Comment: Hash value will not be sent to the Rails server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Comment: @emaillenin what's PHP got to do with ruby/RoR?

Comment: @Vucko Hashes aren't sent to the server, so the server-side language doesn't matter. I've edited the other question to make this clearer.

Comment: @emaillenin - it doesn't appear in this question that the URL comes from a browser request...

Comment: `"http://{My-Domain}/signin#recording"[/.*#(\w+)/, 1]` => `"recording"`. Your question is too broad and have many possible answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `URI.parse` to parse the `URL`, and then look for the attribute [`fragment`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#fragment):

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://www.example.com/signin#recording'
uri = URI.parse url
uri.fragment
# => "recording"
```

Comment: How to get complete url in ruby because request.original_url give url without anchor.

Comment: that's because the browser does not pass the anchor to the server - see the comments under your question...

Comment: @UriAgassi so I was right about my comment ;)

Comment: @emaillenin - doesn't change the fact the it wasn't apparent from the question - it could easily ask about URLs coming from other places - exactly the reason the attribute `fragment` exists in the first place :-P

Comment: But my assumption was based on the tag [ruby-on-rails], but you could have been right as well :)