# how to get #jumper part from url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, segment

My Url is

```
http://www.domain.com/seg_one/seg_two/seg_three#jumper
```

I want to get #jumper part of current url

Comment: Similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can get this by simply [`location.hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) property of `window` object. i.e.

```
window.location.hash;  // will give you #jumper.
```

From here once you have it on the client side, do anything you want with it. You can send it back to server by even making an ajax call.

Comment: we want in php not in js

Comment: Where it is written in your Question that you want it in `php`, besides, JS works pretty well with php also.

Comment: At the end of the tunnel, ultimately its all `HTML`, styled by `CSS` and powered by `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` is called a `fragment`. The problem is that browsers won't transmit those to the server so there is now way to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it via javascript (see below) and make an ajax request to use it in the back-end(PHP):

```
window.location.href
```

You can condition the ajax call:

```
address = window.location.href;
index = address.str.indexOf("#");
if(typeof index !='null') {
    var term = str.slice(address.str.indexOf("#")+1, address.length);
    console.log(term);//will display jumper
    //send it via AJAX
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$third = $this->uri->segment(3);
$thirdArr = explode('#', $third);
$hash = $thirdArr[1];
```