# Jquery AJAX request with hash deep in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I am working on embedding Sisense into my site and I would like to explore embedding via AJAX rather than the dated Iframe (since I'll have to use a hosted JS file to bind to events, only accessible via a GUI).

I have the following AJAX call (url masked with fake IP):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://99.9.9.123/app/main#/dashboards/4251cc98nc83/widgets/n128cm836chna1?embed=true&r=false',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {},
    success: function(result){
        $("#container").html(result);
    }
});
```

When I make this call, the request URL looks like it has been truncated to the location of the hash:

[image]
(Ignore the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. I will be changing that in my environment)

Any idea what is going on here and why I cannot access the full URL via AJAX? I have no access to changing the URL.

Comment: The hash is never sent to the server.  That's how URLs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hints from the comment provided, I'm seeing that the hash is never passed to the server:

[Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby#answer-940923)

My thought was to decode the hash, hit it via AJAX, and decode it on the server.

Another solution I'm thinking of is to create an endpoint on the server that I can call and pass parameters that correspond to the appropriate dashboard/widget ids. Haven't implemented yet; just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with $.ajax in jQuery < 3. Indeed everything after # is stripped out from URL. It was fixed in jQuery version 3:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/2721