# Can not get query string value using GET method using PHP

Tags: php

I have an issue.I can't fetch the query string value using php GET method .I am explaining my code below.

```
http://oditek.in/spesh/#/resetPass?m_i=bbc9a02e5e63f742
```

from the above URL i need to fetch the query string value for that i did like below.

```
$id=$_GET['m_i'];
echo  $id;
```

when i did echo this `$id` it showing me blank.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: take note that after the `#`, the rest of it will not be caught by the server

Comment: That's because you have # in the url. Anything present after # isn't considered.

Comment: Everything after `#` counts as url fragment and does not get sent to the server. Remove it.

Comment: actually i am using `Angular.js` for front end.By default the html5 mode is disable from the begining is there any other solution?

Comment: It really does not matter what you use as frontend. In the end the browser makes the HTTP request. Remove the hashtag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby)

Comment: You can get the real url from Borwser Inspect Element. What I get is "Request URL:http://oditek.in/spesh/".

Comment: @CharlotteDunois : i removed the hash tag but the still the same issue is coming.

Comment: Are you sure you removed `#`?

Comment: yes,now url is like this `http://oditek.in/spesh/resetPass?m_i=bbc9a02e5e63f742`.