# Laravel 5 route url filtering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Hello i'm using laravel 5 for my project.

i have routes like :

```
news/some-news-title/galery?page=2#photo/
```

it works great for my paginating galleries. But i saw that when i add extra parameter end of to url , it still works.

example :

```
news/some-news-title/galery?page=2/amp
news/some-news-title/galery?page=2/asdasd
```

normally it should not work. But it shows same gallery page.

i tried some codes , but it did not work for me :

```
Route::any('news/{any}/{any?}/amp', function(){
   return 'error';
});

Route::any('news/{any}/{any}/{any}', function(){
   return 'error';
});
```

when tried these codes , it still opens same page.

How can i block or redirect this parameters to 404 page ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> it works great for my paginating galleries. But i saw that when i add
>   extra parameter end of to url , it still works.

It seems that it is the right behaviour .

Lets have a look at your URL

It may be something like http://example.com/news/some-news-title/galery?page=2#photo/anythingelse

I have checked it at http://www.freeformatter.com and it says :

[image]

Now Your are concerned about last part of url(Hash).

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) :

> The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document.

In simple word you can't filter the Hash Part because it belongs to current document and treated as **single and last portion of URL**.

Comment: i want to filter last part after hash , is it same for last section of url ? `/anythingelse` part

Comment: for example :   `/news/news-post-title/galery?page=7` is ok ,  but i can't block `/news/news-post-title/galery?page=7/asdasda`

Comment: In simple word browser doesn't send the hash part to server but you can use javascript to get last portion and then send that part by ajax to server.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby

and http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/15/read-the-anchor-part-of-the-url-with-php/

Comment: If you want to block "/asdasda" the you should move that portion out of Hash Part of URL.

Comment: i will try it !