# How can I retrieve a URL variable in coldfusion from a URL with a hashtag?

Tags: url, coldfusion

I have the following URL
    `file.cfm#widget=details?id_code=123`

I'm trying to display or use the id_code var...
`<cfoutput>#url.id_code#</cfoutput>`

But it gives me the error `Element COURSE_CODE is undefined in URL.`

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: id_code or COURSE_CODE? Which variable are you really trying to set and output? That error would not be produced based on the code I have seen.

Comment: Sorry, the error it gives me is Element ID_CODE is undefined in URL.

Comment: it might be the #widget=details is messing things up so that cf doesn't even get the id_code

Comment: yeah, i just checked locally, and that #widget-details is meaning cf doesn't get the id - usually in urls the # would be at the end - like file.cfm?id_code=123#widget-details

Comment: The vars after the # in the URL come in from javascript, is there a way I can use those vars in coldfusion?

Comment: can you put the # after the ? like file.cfm?id_code=123#widget=details - then cf can get the id_code like normal, at the moment with file.cfm#widget=details?id_code=123 cf isn't getting anything after file.cfm

Comment: @elixireu How are you generating this URL? `id_code` is part of url hash *not* param.

Comment: What do you see when you do this?  `<cfdump var="#url#">`

Comment: This javascript you mentioned.  Why is it doing what it's doing?

Comment: Hi Dan, `<cfdump var="#url#">` displays nothing, but `<cfdump var="#VARIABLES#">` displays the var I need - 1st column, `'struct' 'CFQUERY.EXECUTIONTIME' 'DBFIELDCOURSES'` 2nd column displays the vars `'n^id| t^title| t^subtitle| t^code'` I hope you follow me.

Comment: The javascript is calling an API to display the data, but uses the var ID in the URL to display the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a Fragment URL. Unfortunately, this (and everything behind it) isn't passed in your HTTP request, and isn't readable by your server side ColdFusion code.

[Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby)