# How to get URL parameters in ESPOCRM tpl file?

Tags: php, espocrm

I have a URL like **http://localhost/core/crm/#Request/view/5afe67cf12187** and I wanted to get the value **5afe67cf12187** in tpl file. Please help me to get this value in tpl file in **ESPOCRM**.

Comment: You can't read that using PHP. The hash and everything after is a client-only part that won't even be sent to the server. You need to read that using JS. Then you need to send it to the server using JS and Ajax or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby)