# Read full request URL in Play Web Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to read full URL which comes with #params. How can i read in Play controller? I am able to read query parameters but not route directive

> ex : https://x.app.com/callback#x=1

```
Action.async{ implicit request =>
     val fullUrl = ??? //Read full url of request
}
```

I tried request.uri and request.path. both are not helpful.

```
response of request.uri => /callback
response of request.path => /callback
```

There are no #params in the response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
request.path
```

or

```
request.uri
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass fragment (# part) to server, it is browser only. Use query parameter instead

Comment: I do not have any control on the incoming request. that comes from external service like oauth.

Comment: Doesnt have external service another api? Searching for fragment on serverside is dead end.