# How to get special part of URL using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have an url like this one,

```
https://example.com/folder-name/article-name-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-5b5964935583202d2beff315.html#id-41
```

What I'm trying to do is get **5b5964935583202d2beff315** and **41** in url.

I really want to know how to do this, and I needs help. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby)

Comment: Does the server have `#id-41` when you get it? Is this a string or URL you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "https://example.com/folder-name/dien-hy-cong-luoc-story-of-yanxi-palace-5b5964935583202d2beff315.html#id-41";

preg_match("/^.+-([^.-]+)\.html#id-(\d+)/", $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://example.com/folder-name/dien-hy-cong-luoc-story-of-yanxi-palace-5b5964935583202d2beff315.html#id-41
    [1] => 5b5964935583202d2beff315
    [2] => 41
)
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  ^             : beginning of line
    .+          : 1 or more any character but newline
    -           : a dash
    ([^.-]+)    : group 1, 1 or more any character that is not a dot or dash
    \.          : a dot
    html#id-    : literally 
    (\d+)       : group 2, 1 or more digits
/
```