# Getting hashtags from $request in Yii2

Tags: request, yii2, hashtag

I need to get hashtags from a GET-request, like this:
`/v1/search/search#tag?query=word`
or `/v1/search/search?query=word#tag`
I try to get query string:
`Yii::$app->request->getQueryString()`
But in first case it totally ignores query param, whereas in the second case it finds query param, but ignores hashtag. Is any way to get the hashtag from request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby)

Comment: BTW: if `query` value should be `word#tag`, then you should encode `#` and have something like `?query=word%23tag`. Yii should already do this if you create URLs using UrlManager.

Answer (score 1):

### You cannot get URI fragment value (hashtag) on the server (directly).

This is not a `Yii` limitation, the anchor `#` part of the url is meant to be used on the client side, and it isn't sent to the server.

According to the [Wikipedia page for URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment):

> Fragments depend on the document MIME type and are evaluated by the client (web browser).

> Clients are not supposed to send URI fragments to servers when they retrieve a document, and without help from a local application (see below) fragments do not participate in HTTP redirections.

You can check by yourself looking at the network traffic, your server logs, `Yii` debugger logs, or at your browser console, for example, if you try to browse `https://example.com/user/123#1234` the server will only get `https://example.com/user/123`.

You could bypass this limitation converting the values to parameters before you send the request.

```
// you could update
https://example.com/user/123#1234
// to
https://example.com/user/123?tag=1234
```