# url_rewrite /#/something/here to /something/here

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I need to configure my Apache instance to redirect the requests from a pattern like

```
/#/something/here
```

to

```
/something/here
```

I tried with

```
RewriteRule /([\#])/something/here /(.)/something/here
```

with no success. Any thoughts?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bad news: Hashes in URLs don't get sent to the server.

The text following the hash is known as a "[fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)" and is only used by the browser.

Comment: I thought that too but I figured out that this just happens if the URL is in a link, if you access the URL by entering it in the address bar the headers are GET /#/something/here HTTP/1.1 ....

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using, but that looks broken to me. I just entered the url `http://entrian.com/#/test` into Firefox 3.5.2, and Wireshark gave me a trace with the opening line: `GET / HTTP/1.1`

Comment: You're right, I made my test using HttpFox add-on and it displayed the wrong headers, thanks