# GET PHP but using # instead of ?=

Tags: php

When using the $_GET[] in php, it searches for a variable e.g ?id=value

Is there a way to call the #value instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because the hash part of the url is client-side only and is not sent to the server.

When you enter an URL such as `http://server.com/dir/file.php?a=1#something` in your browser's URL textbox, the browser opens a connection to the `server.com` and then issues a HTTP command `GET /dir/file.php?a=1 HTTP/1.1`. This is the only data sent to the server. 
Hence, the server never gets the `#something` part, and this means there is no script on server side you could write to read that value.

Similar question explained here: [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer naivists

Comment: +1, absolutely true.  However, here's an example that makes things appear thoroughly confusing: http://www.google.com/#q=test .  Google appears to bend the rules thanks to some clever javascript.  If you clear your cache and watch LiveHTTPHeaders, a request for / is sent (without the fragment), which loads javascript, which triggers a request for the actual search result data (the query string for this request is read from the fragment in Window.location(?) using javascript): GET /search?q=test&fp=1&cad=b HTTP/1.1.  I'm sure there's some interesting reason google does things this way.

Comment: @naivist Interesting. I was convinced having seen the fragment in an URL on the serverside before, but you are right, thus I deleted my answer. Now I only need to find the RFC that says why it is like this. After all, it's a valid URI component.

Comment: Frank Farmer, one of reasons why this may be done is - to let the client stay on the same page without refresh. That is, if you add a link in your page to, say, `samepage.htm#something`, and click that link, your page is not refreshed. However, you can catch that event in javascript, and, using AJAX, call for some more data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around it by getting the fragment via javascript and sending an ajax request with the fragment as the $_GET contents.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your whole case, I may be off track, but there is the possibility of sending the #something to the server via a simple GET type of xmlhttprequest.

Answer (score -4):

Yeah there is a way. I think what you want to do is:

```
$arValues = array_values($_GET);
// whatever else you want to do with the values
```

Comment: He wants to get the URL fragment. What he means by ?= is the regular params, e.g. foo=bar. But he is looking for the value in the URL after #.