# how to get value of a #t=querystring in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use Request.QueryString["var"] to pull the value of http://test.com/test.aspx?var=test into a string

the same thing doesn't work for test.aspx#var=test

how can I get it from that version of a querystring?

Comment: That's a page anchor. I don't think it gets POSTed with the URL.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the part of the url after the # is passed to the web server directly. To access it you would need to do some javascript processing to pass it on.

Comment: oh i see, i'm trying to set the div style properties of a block differently depending on what's in that #var variable, javascript would be the way to go instead you think?

Comment: Yes. That should be easy using a jquery script.

Comment: ok i guess i'll go look for one, never used jquery i'm a novice. if you have time and care to link me to something relevant that'd be awesome, otherwise thanks

Comment: Sure! jQuery takes some getting used to so you should read the getting started intro here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery Then you may want to look at this jQuery add on for url parsing: http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/

Answer (score 6):

The Fragment Identifier (#) is client-side only, you can't get that from server side code.

Comment: Nitpick: It's called **Fragment Identifier**, not "hash value". :-)

Comment: Well you access it with location.hash so that's why I called it that, my bad ;)

Comment: thanks everyone, you all had it right, wish i could award multiples

Answer (score 1):

`#var=test` is not q query string. That's part of the "URL Fragment". In a URL to a web page, it indicates which `<a>` tag to go to.

Comment: thanks everyone, you all had it right, wish i could award multiples