# request.getQueryString() doesn't return the hash part of the query string

Tags: jsp, servlets, query-string

I am using Java EE and `request.getQueryString()` doesn't return the `#hash` part

```
my/page?id=4#hash
```

I am using Struts 2.

Is there any solution?

Comment: not related to Struts2, actually (retagging)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem reading data from servlet get request!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296325/problem-reading-data-from-servlet-get-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash part of the url is (in principle) useful only to the client side, so normally the browser does not send that portion to the server. Are you sure you are interested in reading it, in the server side? Normally, you shoudn't.

For special needs, you can read here 
[How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Comment: access to the hash would be great - jwt tokean after auth provided as a hash in url.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. In many cases the hash tag isn't sent to the server by your client's browser.

For example, requesting this url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923610/java-getquerystring/2923618#2923618
```

Sends a request with these headers to the server:

```
GET /questions/2923610/java-getquerystring/2923618 HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```