# Problem reading data from servlet get request!

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet get request URL like this

```
http://hostname:port/servletname?UA=PC#token=123456
```

How to read values thats available after `#token`?

`request.getParameter(#token)` gives null..

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Krishnan

Answer (score 1):

That's because `#token` isn't a parameter, it's an HTML page anchor reference. In fact, the browser never even *sends* it to the server, it's kept entirely on the browser.

If you need to pass the token to the server, you need to encode it as a parameter, i.e.

> http://hostname:port/servletname?UA=PC&token=123456

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cant change it, because this url comes from third party. Facebook API redirecting this url with token. Is there any way to parse it manually?

Comment: @user658433: You can't parse it on the server because *the server never receives it*. As I said, it's kept on the browser.

Comment: @kris: Javascript, maybe. But a JSP is still server-side.

Answer (score -1):

could you try request.getQueryString() ?

Comment: Yes. tried but not working.. Got only UA=pc itself as a response