# Getting complete URL including malformed part

Tags: c#, url

I am interfacing my application with a third party application, the third party application pass my application at one place with '#' hash as query variable separator than '&' ampersand. C# removes the malformed part of query string, i.e. '#' and all part further right to it. Is there any way to get the whole raw query string including the malformed part, so that I can parse it myself.

There is no provision available to ask third party to correct this issue.

I have tried `Request.QueryString`, `Request.RawQuery`, `Request.Url.Query` but none contain the actual raw query with malformed part. Which means raw query is NOT actual raw query :(
If you could help me, I will be grateful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: Provide an example of such URL

Comment: it is kind of possible to deduce from your question that your application is running on the server, but where is the third party application running? on the server as well? i would not expect a comprehensive response to such a vague question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the contents after the hash in the URL isn't straightforward because it is intended for the client, not your application running on the server. How does the interaction between the two applications happen, perhaps a workaround can be applied?

Also, have you seen this: [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Comment: Thanks, now I am using javascript parsing and redirection technique.