# vb.net if statement using the value of hash in URL

Tags: vb.net, anchor

I have a page with a URL that includes a hash value (www.mysite.com/#123).

What I want to do is use that value to determine what is displayed on the page - much like using a querystring.

I am using the hash value because the content on the page can be changed client side (I am avoiding page reloads where possible) - if the user then links to another page and uses the back button to return, I need to use the hash value to display the page as it was when they left it.

So I'm looking for an if statement that will look something like this:

```
if hashvalue = 123 then
    Do this
else
    do that
End if
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I apologise if my terminology is wrong... please feel free to edit

Comment: So ASP.net on the server? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript `window.location.hash` attribute.

For instance,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onhashchange = function () {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            switch (hash) {
                case "#120": alert("One"); break;
                case "#121": alert("Two"); break;
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <a href="#120">One</a>
      <a href="#121">Two</a>    
    </form>
...
```