# asp.net request url don't return #, and data after #

Tags: asp.net, url, parameters

I have  URL like  - www.mysite.aspx#type  and HttpContext.Current.Request.Url returns just path without # and text after #, just www.mysite.aspx...  Maybe someone have solution? I need this #type to return. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the part after the hash (#). It's on the brower's scope.

You can however get around this by notifying the server from the client what is the full URL. See here: [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Comment: Sorry, these are your options :-)

Comment: I have used jvascript for redirect and setting ?type: <script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.URL.indexOf("#patient") >= 0){ 
     window.location = "../Pages/faq.aspx?type=patient"
    }
  </script>

Comment: After that i can get type with asp. So, thank you very much! )

Answer (score 0):

The part after # (called [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) is never sent to the server by the browser so you can't receive it in asp which is a server side technology.

Comment: Thank you very much! Issue still persists, but it's a big step forward!