# How to get hash in a server side language?

Tags: url, hash

As far as I know, there's no way to get url hash in a server side language since hash urls are not being sent to the server side. One of my co-workers told me that it should be possible in java (jsp) or Ruby. Since I tested it on PHP, but it simply doesn't work. I googled about ruby and jsp, but had no luck. He also mentioned that the first access (http://domain.com/index.php#test ) is accessible from a server side.

in PHP, printing our **$_SERVER** variable doesn't have anything about hash

Is this really possible in other server side languages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, it's a client side only thing.

Slightly longer:
It's called **Fragment identifier** and is client side only - browser doesn't send that part of the url to the server. It's not possible in any language unless you are using some browser implementation (or software) which *would* send that part of url to the server. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier