# Getting path name from URL using Ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I had a doubt regarding RoR. I want to extract the path name from URL present in the Address bar.Suppose i have `"http://localhost:3000/#toregister"` in my address bar and i need only  `#toregister` .So how can i fetch this path name to the controller page using only RoR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [URI](http://apidock.com/ruby/URI) module

```
uri = URI("http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413")
#=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000000b14880 URL:http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413>
uri.fragment
#=> "time=1305298413"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately - you can't do this. This is only client-side available. Check [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987075/4381282) for more

Answer (score 0):

You can't get anchor's value on server side. But if you need to parse existing url string, you may use built-in [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module:

```
URI('http://localhost:3000/#toregister').fragment # returns 'toregister'
```