# How to get URL parameter in PHP

Tags: php

I have this url and i want to get the **circle_id**

```
http://localhost:8888/li.php#/action=1&P=1circle_id=0090000007
```

i have this code

```
$circle_id = $_GET["circle_id"];
echo $circle_id ;
```

but it doesn't return any output

Comment: because you've not a query string. `http://localhost:8888/li.php?action=1&P=1&circle_id=0090000007` is what you want?

Comment: yes is there a way to get circle_id?

Comment: Your URL is missing a '&' sign to separate your variables.

If you do a var_dump($_GET); you would see it.

Comment: basically, everything after # is not sent to php by browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get hash in a server side language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987045/how-to-get-hash-in-a-server-side-language)

Answer (score 0):

query string starts with "?" and concatenate by "&"
Try http://localhost:8888/li.php?action=1&P=1&circle_id=0090000007

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL looks a bit weird, first is what @Federico mentioned, the query mark `?` is not there.

Secondly, you missed the query field `P=1&circle_id=009....`, you should have a `&` to separate each query field. Hopefully it helps.