# Pass URL's with hash value for redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

I'm having some trouble to get the **hash** value from a variable.

I'm using the default action in the `AccountController`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl) { ... }
```

but if I pass this link on:

```
http://localhost:1357/none/Account/LogOn?returnUrl=a/b/c#day-22
```

I can never catch the `#day-22` value

below it's a breakpoint after the login:

[image]

I never get the hash value on the `HttpContext.Request.Url` object.

> **What can I do** to forward the user to the correct URL **with the hash** part?

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya it's not exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to urlencode it.

Try: `http://localhost:1357/none/Account/LogOn?returnUrl=a/b/c%23day-22`

Comment: works lovely, thanks for the idea, it's a simple one that even I didn't thought of testing :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because the URL fragment (the bits after the `#`) is not sent from the browser to the server.

Comment: Oi João. So, how can I get it?

Comment: You need to send that piece of information through other mechanism that actually allows sending information to the server, for example a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` while forming/resolving that part.

Comment: The string never get's to the server... no matter what decode utility I use, The value is not there!