# Encode hash in ReturnUrl ASP.NET Login control

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

We have a ASP.NET login control in our aspx:

```
<asp:Login ID="LogOnControl" runat="server" OnLoginError="OnLogOnError" OnLoggedIn="OnLoggedIn">
```

and in OnLoggedIn we do:

```
protected void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    }
}
```

and our ReturnUrl should be something like `Default.aspx#/Projects`

The problem is that all after hash is trimmed. We need to pass entire URL to server (so encode it somehow).

Comment: Did you try : HttpUtility.UrlEncode?

Comment: yeah might help, but in which event should I encode it? at the moment it is being sent to the server I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jabko87 - you cannot get values after # because it is not being sent to the server. You must develop your own mechanism to handle it.

Compare: [Pass URL's with hash value for redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053096/pass-urls-with-hash-value-for-redirection)

And: [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Comment: seems I found a solution, I put hidden input to aspx where I save window.location.hash and on server it comes as POST parameter and I append it to URL where I redirect, seems to work well

Comment: Exactly that is what I meant by "developing own mechanism" :) Glad you've made it;)

Comment: Thanks for leading me to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by defining hidden input on aspx page:

```
<input type="hidden" id='<%= ReturnUrlHash %>' name='<%= ReturnUrlHash %>' />
```

and filling it with JS:

```
document.getElementById('<%= ReturnUrlHash %>').value = window.location.hash;
```

and on server side in Logon.aspx.cs I did:

```
public const string ReturnUrlHash = "returnUrlHash";
protected void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(ReturnUrlHash))
        {
            returnUrl += Request.Form[ReturnUrlHash];
        }

        Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```