# Spring security Saved URL RequestCache does not store # (hash)

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

I am using Spring security to protect resources on our application. Unfortunately, spring does not store the full url's that include a # . E.g.:

```
example.com/account/file#1234
```

The `#1234` is not stored in the request cache before being redirected to the login page and the security process. Once returned from authentication, the url redirected to is :

```
example.com/account/file
```

Is there any way to make spring store the full url?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side, the hash part is not a part of the URI

Comment: I know it is not. Hence my question on how to make spring store it. I don't think the link you refer to is relevant. Thanks.

Comment: It is fully relevant. If you have a closer look, you will see that the server cannot fetch information which is never sent from the client, i.e. the browser never forwards the fragment part to the server. You will have to let a piece of Javascript send this as a request parameter.

Comment: the question should not have been closed. My redirect is generated on the server and therefore needs to be store on the server for later redirect to the client. Too bad stackoverflow allows people that do not understand the question to just close it!!!