# Redirect to the page containing # (hash) sign after login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security and wondering how can I implement redirection after succesfull login to the source page if that page contains `#` (hash) sign.

Right now I use `always-use-default-target="false"` and it works fine on URL kind of: `/path/to/page/`.

But when the URL become to `#/path/to/page` it doesn't make any redirections.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: can you provide example paths

Comment: I did it in the question: /path/to/page/ and #/path/to/page

Comment: [You can't use hash on server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side).

Comment: @Xaerxess: I know. The question is how to add this hash into URL in order to redirect to it afgter login. Right now Spring ignore that hash

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solution I used at the end:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#auth-form').submit(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash) el.prop('action', el.prop('action') + '#' + unescape(hash.substring(1)));
    return true;
  });
});
```

This snippet addes the hash to authorization form's action attribute and Spring redirect you to the URL of kind: `#/path/to/page` without any problem.

Comment: This works great if using angular-js with a spring backend. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea! Use this if you don't want to use jQuery.
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

            var form = document.getElementById('auth-form');

            var hash = window.location.hash;

            form.action = form.action + '#' + decodeURI(hash.substring(1));

        });`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is the old question, but during my recent research in this topic, I found that the problem is common and still exists (especially in case of modern AngularJS front-end apps with back-end security). I'd like to share my solution with you.

On the login page, e.g., /login.html, put following code before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    document.cookie="hashPart=" + window.btoa(hash);
</script>
```

Note (1): btoa() function works in IE >= 10 (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp), for older browsers use jQuery equivalent.

Note (2): The encryption of the # part of URL is necessary as it may contain special characters, which are not allowed to be stored in cookie value string.

From the server side you have to modify `onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)` method of class implementing `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` interface.

In my case, I simply extend the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class and override the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method using its original code. Then I obtain the *hashPart* cookie value from the request, decode it and add to resolved redirect URL. My code fragment below:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // ... copy/paste original implementation here, until ...

    // Use the DefaultSavedRequest URL
    String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();

    for (Cookie cookie : req.getCookies()) {
        if (cookie.getName().equals("hashPart")) {
            targetUrl += new String(Base64Utils.decodeFromString(cookie.getValue()));
            cookie.setMaxAge(0); // clear cookie as no longer needed
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            break;
        }
    }

    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}
```

Finally, just inject your success handler class to your Spring Security configuration, as described in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100458/3076403

I'm looking forward to your comments or other solutions to this problem.