# Moving Spring Security To Java Config, where does authentication-success-handler-ref go?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Our app has a custom success handler for successful logins. It basically redirects them to the page they were on when their session expired.

We're moving to a Java config rather than a spring xml config. The rest of the config went very smoothly, but we can't find where to put the authentication-success-handler-ref attribute of the security:form-login tag.

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
  ...
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
  <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/sites"
                     authentication-failure-url="/login"
                     authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
 ...
```

Here's our config, so far.

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
       .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
        .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
          .failureUrl("/login")
          .and()
        .logout()
          .permitAll()
          .and()
  }
```

Also, we can't find where to put default-target-url, but that is definitely less important.

Caveat, we're actually using Groovy, but the code is basically the same as a Java config.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All settings can be done inside the global configure method. Add the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
        .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/sites")
          .failureUrl("/login")
          .successHandler(yourSuccessHandlerBean) // autowired or defined below
          .and()
        .logout()
          .permitAll()
          .and()
  }
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can specify an alternative constructor which takes a boolean specifying if you always want to redirect to the specified URL after a succesful login - for example,  defaultSuccessUrl("/sites", true). Note if this boolean is not specified, <b> spring will instead redirect you to the url you were trying to access before being redirected to the authentication page. </b>

Comment: What about remember-me authentication? How to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create bean extending `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` or `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. For example:

```
@Bean
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("/secure/");
    return successHandler;
}
```

Then you have to setup it on bean extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
```

Comment: Trouble is, the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter requires implementing the attemptAuthentication method which we might not want to do if we already have a custom authentication provider.

Comment: FYI, The `successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter` is used to have SpringSecurity respond to a query parameter if the authentication is successful. So, you might have something like: `successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("next");` and then, if the url was: `http://localhost:8080/login?next=/foo`, on successful authentication, the success handler would redirect to `/foo`. NOTE: Things might have changed since 2014, but since I found this in a google search, I thought I would provide this info.