# How to configure Spring ACL without XML file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-security, acl

I am trying to add ACL capabilities to my server. I have configured spring security using java file and would like to add ACL in the same manner. How should I do it? All the tutorials I found used XML file.

**SecurityInit:**

```
@Order(1)
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@Component
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"test.package"})
public class SecurityConfig extends 

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...
    @Autowired
    protected void registerAuthentication(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

//  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100458/162345
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(...)
                .addFilterBefore(...)

//                TODO: create a better way to differentiate login to signup
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(noRedirectForAnonymous)
                    .and()

                .formLogin()
                    .successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                    .and()

                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(noRedirectLogoutSuccessHandler)
                    .and()

                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/keywords/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6, accepted):

There is no way to configure spring acl without xml file. This is mentioned in spring docs itself.Refer to spring documentation.

Comment: This answer should be update cause the answer from @Fiore proves this is not true anymore. His code also proves it.

Answer (score 14):

You can configure spring acl with Java configuration class as follow

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class ACLConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

EhCacheBasedAclCache aclCache() {
    EhCacheFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManager = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.setName("aclCache");
    factoryBean.setCacheManager(cacheManager.getObject());
    return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(factoryBean.getObject());
}


LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
    return new BasicLookupStrategy(dataSource, aclCache(), aclAuthorizationStrategy(), new ConsoleAuditLogger());
}


AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
    return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ACL_ADMIN"),
        new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ACL_ADMIN"),
        new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ACL_ADMIN"));
}

@Bean
JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
    JdbcMutableAclService service = new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
    service.setClassIdentityQuery("select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_class', 'id'))");
    service.setSidIdentityQuery("select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_sid', 'id'))");
    return service;
}

@Bean
AclMasterService masterService() {
    return new AclMasterService();
}

@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler(){
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService()));
    return expressionHandler;
}
}
```

The important aspect of the configuration are extend from

> *GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration*

override the method

> *createExpressionHandler*

and enable the Pre and Post anotations with the follow anotation at the begining of the class

> @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled =
>   true)

Now you can use anotations like

> *@PreAuthorize('hasPermission(#object,read)')*

see the Contact sample of Spring Security or the  [spring security reference guide](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwjnxpj4qdPHAhUGph4KHUB1CrI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.spring.io%2Fautorepo%2Fdocs%2Fspring-security%2F4.0.x%2Freference%2Fpdf%2Fspring-security-reference.pdf&ei=RUnkVaeQFIbMesDqqZAL&usg=AFQjCNGJVggsTKfj7K23ec_5JTAM2hnMHw&sig2=k-O4OgrZYPj2RUjm26WMNA) for more uses of @Pre and @Post anotations. 
This configuration class was tested on Spring 4 , Spring Security 4.0.1 and Spring Security ACL 3.1.2. If you want configure the authentication you can use  a different Java class or override the configure method from this. If you already have a configured ehcache this configuration could not work correctly due to the ehcache is a singleton class and this configuration try to create a new one.

Comment: You don't have to extend the `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` configuration. You just have to expose a `@Bean` of type `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)`

Comment: What version of EHCache do you use? This example does not compile for 2.10.4, 2.10.3, 2.10.2, didn't check others.