# How to get query in the URL after #

Tags: php

I am using PHP and want to check links of the same page but with different trailing info.

The URL to the page normally is http://www.mypage.com/?about but if the user accessed it by clicking on the link SEND the user get send to http://www.mypage.com/?about#send

If the user clicked INFO they go to http://mypage.com/?about#info

Question how do I check for `#` and what comes after it?
I tried `$_SERVER[query_string]` and it shows `about#send` and I only need to check for what comes after the number sign `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code after reading your url :

```
$s =  $_SERVER[query_string];
$url = explode('#',$s);
echo $url[1];
```

In this code $url[1] is the value that you want.
Split the url by #,makes an array.

Comment: No. The hash portion is not sent to the server.

Comment: Read the question,tried $_SERVER[query_string] and it shows about#send.So he has the url.

Comment: Unless there's something the OP is not telling us, that still doesn't make it possible.

Comment: @SamanGholami  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Comment: @iight Maybe the user changes the url.Client side isn't good solution.

Comment: this is simply not possible. your code will not work.

Comment: @iight Yes,but it is possible!if $s contains the url,that has # sign ,this is worked.You can test it.but if $s hasn't the url, you right.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `$_SERVER[query_string]` **will not** get the # and everything after it - making your code moot and not correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do it client side , but here's the php code than can do it:

```
<?
echo parse_url("http://mypage.com?about#send",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
?>
Outout : send
```

Comment: That second part is simply copied from Saman and then slightly modified ... besides, the first part already works (theoretically).

Comment: Ok i'm answering more than 5 questions at a time and i was not giving pay much attension to others asnwers . I'm sorry for the similarity but promise me i did not see that. You are right but i did not copied. Look at my profile and the answers that i given in these 20minutes and you will see that im not lying

Comment: Well, at least clean it up so that it doesn't throw notices for undefined constant `query_string` (and use upper case) and undefined index `1` if there's no hash ... which there isn't anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The hash portion (everything that follows the # sign) is never sent to the server and you cannot get in in your PHP script. You can manipulate it only with javascript. This is achieved with the `window.location.hash` property.

Comment: This information can be found in the marked duplicates as well, no need to write another answer here :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice there was a duplicate. I will vote to close. Thanks.