# Grabbing hash link from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I have url as: **/#profile/7**
how to make it grab that last number from there?
I'm looking for creating an mysql connection from that, SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE id=':profile'
Also, is it safe this way, is it even possible to make a connection?
This is what I've got.

```
<script>
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(6);
      alert (hash);
</script>
```

Comment: The hash is not sent to the server by default. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.match(/\/(\d)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `split()` instead of substring:

```
var parts = window.location.hash.split('/');
var id = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Comment: But can you answer one more question?
Is it safe, using this kind of method?

Comment: Yes, this is safer than the substring method as this does not impose any restrictions on the length of what comes before the id in the hash.