# How to get the site url with bookmark in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the absolute url of .net application with bookmark.

So if the request is coming from - `www.mysite.com/myapplication/Home/Index#about`

then how to get the above url in .net application?

I tried `HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` but it is returning - `www.mysite.com/myapplication/Home/Index` but how to get `bookmark ("#about")` part of url?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible: anything after the # is not sent by the browser, it is only used inside the loaded page for navigating to anchors.

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't  transmit that part to server.you should use java Script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side) answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

assuming that the variable url holds your actual url

```
string[] bookmark = url.Split('#');
and the bookmark[1] will hold the Value of your bookmark, also.

string bookmark = url.Replace(HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri(url), string.Empty);
```

Comment: there no url variable....your answer is based on wrong assumption....how did you got variable URL?

Comment: No it doesn't hold "#" part of URL