# How to get full url path in controller mvc1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

there is url like

> www.test.local/itsoftware/#/results?d=S102&s=S102

when i am getting the url in controller irt is showing

> www.test.local/itsoftware/

only. not complete path, i read through below code

> ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the browser doesn't send the content after the hash to the server, since it is supposed to be used only by the user agent, so you can't retrieve the address with the hash value server-side.

You can take a look at this question, which offer some workarounds to solve this (using ASP.NET webforms, but you can adapt the strategy used to MVC): [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Comment: Actually we need a `#` symbol in URL, so that i change a URL path as per my requirement after that i change it through javascript. any way thanks for a valuable information.