# Spring URL pattern with a sharp character

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I create a new filter in the web initializer in my app, and I need to use that when enter to a certain url

```
 servletContext.addFilter("securityForDetails", DelegatingFilterProxy.class )
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/#/list");
```

the problem is that when the I enter to this url, the filter never activates. But when I removed the sharp character `("/list")` it works.

I know it works with a regular expression, and I tried `/*/list` for example, but again, this doesn't work.

How can I make it work ?

Comment: why are you using `#` in the URL pattern? Try `/**/list`

Comment: cause the url is `localhost:8080/#/list`

I tried with `/**/list` but it doesn't work

Comment: What follows `#` in a url is called a fragment and is not sent to the server (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/318581/1567456)). As such, you can’t have a url like that without the help of JavaScript.