# Could not fetch the URL from page_load event with Request.URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a URL. http://website.com/ap/mob/en#contactus. I want to catch the full URL including #contactus. I have tried to catch the URL from Page_load event with Request.Url.AbsoluteUri but my purpose is not getting solved. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript to get the full link then pass it to the code behind

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function JavaScriptFunction() {
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnResultValue.ClientID %>').value = document.URL;
    }

</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResultValue" Value="0" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button_Get" runat="server" Text="run" OnClick="Button_Get_Click" OnClientClick="JavaScriptFunction();" />
```

then from the code behind get the value of hiddenfield which contains the current full URL

```
    protected void Button_Get_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fullURL = hdnResultValue.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, since the browser does not send the hash part to the server. There are [workarounds involving JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side), of course, but those open up your application to script injection.

Here's [what Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier):

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the
>   URI: namely, **its processing is exclusively client-side with no
>   participation from the web server** — of course the server typically
>   helps to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the
>   processing of fragments. When an agent (such as a Web browser)
>   requests a web resource from a Web server, **the agent sends the URI to
>   the server, but does not send the fragment**. Instead, the agent waits
>   for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the
>   resource according to the document type and fragment value.

Answer (score 0):

'#' in the Url is generally used to take user to the different section of the same page. The request will not go to server if url includes '#'.

Can you provide more detail on the scenario you have?