# Can't get parameter from url via query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, query-string, google-signin

I am implementing google login on my site.
Problem is that when google redirect me back to my site (after confirmation) I can't get access token from query string.
This is URL:

```
http://localhost/mysite/west/Default.aspx#state=/profile&access_token=ya29.qQDrtcVtgOEbS86Bg10puFG3dksJz74BlrEGulHldlJW2o5qQ6g7ilF17zQsm8iMLG0C82PQyp2Z-g&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

I suspect that this `#state=/profile` make some issue but can't handle it.
Am I missing something?

Comment: It's the `#` which should be `?` for ASP.NET to identify it as query string.

Comment: But this is what I get from google. How can I get query string then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If URL is like this , note that there is **#** after `Default.aspx` , it is not **?**, then there is no direct way to get get querystring ( they are known as **URL fragments** not *querystring*), they are meant to be parse at client side and server side don't have access to `URL Fragments`.

`http://localhost/mysite/west/Default.aspx#state=/profile&access_token=ya29.qQDrtcVtgOEbS86Bg10puFG3dksJz74BlrEGulHldlJW2o5qQ6g7ilF17zQsm8iMLG0C82PQyp2Z-g&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`

Link contains # ,means an anchor, a position, on a webpage. The browser sends a GET request to the server containing only the address of the entire page, with no anchor, fragment or whatever. When the server returns the page, the browser knows where to position it so the location of the anchor is visible. In clientside or Javascript it is possible as it has access to the anchor.

Read this - [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Comment: I inspect url in javascript and if it contains # I remove it and submit form via js again and then I can get querystring. So i did find workaround but why google rerurn me url like this? Do I have to make this double dorm submita?

Comment: @1110 ,yes you are right, you have to do double post , to get querystring, ( which were `url fragments` ). You need to check with `Google` , may be there you have some setup that points to client side handling, and `Google` applied logic to send you as `URL fragments`, that will be helpful for clientside handling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

document.URL to get the url.

Then split the url by #state=/profile&

Then the second part of the array split by &.

Then each section split by first =

There may be a more elegant solution but this should work.