# Querystring variable use in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to accept my querystring value in MVC Controller.I tried to take it as a parameter also but it also not accept.Because i wanted to confirm this login request comes from  inbox.

```
http://localhost:58692/Account/Login?returnFrom=#inbox
```

My MVC controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(User user, string returnUrl) 
{
    if (Request.QueryString["returnFrom"] != null) // this comes as a null
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know if querystring parameters are passed when you have a POST method on controller instead of GET. You could use returnFrom as one of the form hidden field in that case.

Comment: In the login i want it to confirm this request is normal or this request is comes from Email/Inbox

Comment: In that case, you could have another method/link that can be part of your controller that deals with logging in if it comes from a link/inbox.

Comment: @shahkalpesh could you please show me some example pls

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You can't use a query string in a POST request. If you want to pass a parameter t your action, just use it as a hidden input in your form.

Comment: @TechGuy: I dont have a handy example but you could use a different method that allows GET with a guid as a querystring. That guid can contain reference to user name, let the user enter the password. I am basing this based on emails sent by sites when someone registers and gets activation link in the email.

Comment: @ataravati cant use hidden input know ? because this click comes from email

Comment: If it comes from email, then it can't be a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because everything after `#` is client side. The `#` in the URL defines a link to a named anchor, The query string behind the `#` will not be sent to IIS server. As this is client side you need to escape the `#` from the URL - you can't get it on the server because the browser's already stripped it off. try this:

```
http://localhost:58692/Account/Login?returnFrom=inbox
```

For doing that you need to write some JavaScript codes, So you can use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two Login actions (GET and POST):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) 
{
    if (Request.QueryString["returnFrom"] != null) 
    {
        // return the Login view... 
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user) 
{
    // Check if the user is authorized...
}
```

And, as Sirwan said, you need to remove `#` from the URL:

```
http://localhost:58692/Account/Login?returnFrom=inbox
```