# Routing in a Single Page Application with a different home page

Tags: javascript, html, routes, pushstate, hashchange

I have a single page application - which means everything on the server gets redirected to a single `index.html` file which does the heavy lifting and routing using the HTML5 history api ([pushstate](/questions/tagged/pushstate)).

Now, I want to add a new landing page to the side - let's call it `landing.html` and I want clients to first get to `landing.html` when they access `/` and `index.html` if they access any other route.

Now IE9 does not support the HTML5 history API, so using "hash urls" paths like `/books/authors` become `/#!/books/authors` in it. Since the hash section of the URL [is not sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/318581/1348195) as far as the server is concerned all paths are `/` which means I can't route to `landing.html` or `index.html` based on that logic.

I've thought of a hack - redirecting URLs with `/` to `landing.html`, detecting `#!` on the client, adding a cookie on the server (or client) called `notReallyHomePage` and redirecting to the correct page based on the cookie on the server. This is really hacky and not a good solution.

What would be the correct way to deal with routing in this case?

<sup>My backend is in ASP.NET MVC but I don't think that's relevant to the question</sup>

Comment: Why not use the routing features provided by ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Antony because that's not how single page applications work. Routing is done on the client side - so you don't actually need to hit the server when the user clicks on a link. The advantage is that most routes only need JSON from the server (and not markup) and others can skip hitting the server altogether.

Comment: You probably want something like an index / container page that has your routing logic. That page loads in partials depending on the chosen route. Since your routes aren't being sent to the server, I don't think it's possible to immediately load the correct page.

Comment: Have a look at http://projects.jga.me/routie/. Seems like thing for the job

Comment: @Cerbrus that would still mean another round trip on the client.

Comment: Yes it would. I don't know of a different option though.

Comment: I might be missing something but why not config it using uirouter with `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/landing");` where `.state('landing', {
      url: "/landing",
      templateUrl: "partials/landing.html"
    })` with another state for index which will use the index.html in its  templateUrl ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir that would, for one, require loading Angular itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm... What's the content of landing.html? From its name I'm guessing it's a pretty simple page.

Couldn't you have its contents be a part of index.html and hide/show it according to the "first time user" logic?
Or if landing.html is some weird page created by your marketing or something, then place it in an iframe which hides/shows according to the same logic.

(obviously when you show landing.html then you hide index.html)

Comment: No, half the point of having the landing page is not to load index.html in its entirety.

Comment: Well, in that case, it seems like your cookie solution is the best way to go about it. Like you said, call it 'landingPageVisited' or something, and by default '/' would redirect to landing.html, unless the cookie has been set to true. Doesn't sound *that* hack-y :)