# Altering HTTP_REFERER for use in Django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates, anchor

In a Django template, the following takes me to the referring page:

```
<a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">Referring Page</a>
```

But if I were using [anchor tags](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html), and the referring page was **http://example.com/example/#section7**, `{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}` wouldn't contain the anchor information.

Is there a way I can alter `{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}` (for instance, in my views.py) such that the anchor tag information is preserved?

Comment: This SO link might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the anchor `#` value is never transferred to the server side. Its is purely a client site thing to jump to defined parts of a page.

Somewhat unrelated: that is why, years ago, Google came up with the `#!`, an anchor marker that the Google bot would spider, instead of ignore like the regular `#` value. The biggest user for that was Twitter, iirc. With Javascript's `pushstate()` becoming a thing, the `#!` got forgotten.

Back on topic, the server will never know about any `#` or `#!` values, and thus the `HTTP_REFERER` will not contain it.

Comment: Okay then, seems like I'll be constructing this on my own. Thanks.