# Can't catch the URL parameters with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, fitbit

I'm trying to capture the parameter values from the callback URL coming from the Fitbit API.

The call back URL looks like below,

http://localhost:9000/callback#access_token=********&user_id=*******&scope=sleep+settings+nutrition+activity+social+heartrate+profile+weight+location&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=30418415

I have stated by callback URL in the fitbit API as http://localhost:9000/callback.

My ExpressJS code is as below.

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();


app.use(morgan(':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] :response-time ms'));


app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
    var access_token = req.param('access_token') || null;
    var user_id = req.param('user_id') || null;

    res.send(access_token + ' ' + user_id);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

I can't figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # symbol in an URL is to introduce ***framgent identifier***. So your callback url `http://localhost:3000/callback#access_token=********&user_id=*******&scope=sleep+settings+nutrition+activity+social+heartrate+profile+weight+location&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=30418415` will only get the `http://localhost:3000/callback` not sending any parameters to your server. So, you can not get these parameters in your server directly.

However there is solution to this. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586300/6880789).

Answer (score 0):

> req.param('token') is depreciated   use req.params.token pass the value directly into the url

if you are using req.params specify you key params in the url

```
   app.get('/callback/:access_token/:user_id', function(req, res) {
   //url ==> localhost:9000/callback/1233/123
    var access_token = req.params.access_token || null;
        var user_id = req.params.user_id || null;
           console.log(req.params)
        res.send(access_token + ' ' + user_id);
    });
```

---

> if you want the catch the value in the url means use req.query instead of req.params pass the value using the key of req.query

```
app.get('/callback',function(req, res) {
    var access_token = req.query.access_token || null;
    var user_id = req.query.user_id || null;
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send(access_token + ' ' + user_id);
});
```