# .net core app losing # location on redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a .net core 1.1 app which uses client side hash navigation on some pages.  For example, `http://www.mypage.com/foo#bar`.  The problem is that if the user is not logged in and /foo requires authentication, we use a `returnUrl` to send them back after they log in.  The route should be `/login?returnUrl=/foo#bar` but the `#bar` portion is getting lost.

All of this used to work before we converted to .net core (several months back).  Does anyone know how to get this to work in .net core?  I've tried to step through the request and everything from the `#` on is lost.  Even using `Request.GetDisplayUrl()` only shows the url up to before the `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to get this to work in .net core?

Can't be done with server side redirect.  [The hash value is never sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side) so if you redirect the browser will just throw the hash value away.

You'll either have to write javascript to send the hash to the server via querystring/post-body or store the value in local-storage/cookie client side and add the value after redirect.

Comment: Is this new to .net core? This same basic functionality worked before we moved to .net core.

Comment: The Hash is **never** sent to the server by **any** browser.  So based on what you're saying/what you are describing, information about how this was *working* before is missing.  The information I'm describing about the hash has *nothing* to do with any *server side technology*.

Comment: I dug into the old repo for our pre-core code and found there indeed was some query string magic going on behind the scenes which is why "it worked before".  Thanks for your help Eric.