# How to get the complete url of current page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page have url "http://localhost:1099/call.aspx#3d7b6b" I have used HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri but it shows me only this 
 http://localhost:1099/call.aspx .. I want to get complete url

Comment: You can't.  The URL fragment is not sent to the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)