# Make anchor in link url available in template

Tags: typo3, typoscript

If I set a link in Backend to a specific content element on a page (http://www.test.url/example#999), is there any chance to get this anchor-id in the target template?

Comment: No. The hash portion of the URL is not send to the server in the first place. You only have access to this on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the hash-value is not part of the http request.
Here is an example on how to access the hash on the client side via JavaScript: [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

It is of course possible to convert the hash to a get or post request on the client side.