# Change HTML ID's from url path?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 sites. We will call them site1.com and site2.com

When a user visits site1.com I would like it to redirect them to site2.com. Easy to do

However, if a person was to visit site1.com/# I would like that to redirect them to site2.com and whatever # they put will be added to the body tags of site2.com as a class. so if they were to go to site1.com/6 `<body class="6">` for example. Basically taking the path of the first site and adding that as a class on the body tag of site 2. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this

Comment: For ideas, see [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586300/924299).

Answer (score 0):

This will require collaboration between both domains.<sup>if done with JavaScript, not sure about PHP</sup>

On site1.com, redirect to a new path with the pathname like so (this is assuming of course, that the page will be shown to all locations matching `site1.com/*`):

```js
location = "http://site2.com/"+location.pathname
```

On site2.com, receive this, then use `classList.addClass(name)` to `document.body` like so:

```js
document.body.classList.add(location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you can get the url path info with `$info = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];` if the URL is 'site1.com/5' the result would be '/5'. After that you can redirect the user with  `header('Location: site2.com'.$info);`